# Difference between 'bc' and 'bc -l' in Bash when I try to find modulus of a number

Tags: bc

Why does Unix give the result 0 when I execute the following command?

```
echo "7%2" | bc -l
```

And give result 1 when I execute the following command?

```
echo "7%2" | bc
```

Comment: See [man 1 bc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc) under the "MATH LIBRARY" heading. There are some functions that require the library, and additionally it effects the `scale` defaulting to 20. Modulo does not.

Comment: I edited the tags. This is purely about `bc`, not `unix` or `bash` as previously tagged.

Answer (score 1):

> why does Unix gives result 0 when I execute the command: echo "7%2" | bc -l

From the `bc` manual:

> If bc is invoked with the -l option, a math library is preloaded and the default scale is set to 20.

And

> expr % expr
>
> The result of the expression is the "remainder" and it
> is computed in  the following way. To compute a%b,
> first a/b is
> computed to scale digits. That result is used to compute a-(a/b)*b
> to  the scale of the maximum of scale+scale(b) and scale(a). If
> scale is set to zero and  both  expressions are integers this
> expression is the integer remainder function.

So:

```
 a=7    b=2
 a/b = 7 / 2 = 3.50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 7%2 = a-(a/b)*b =
     = 7 - (7/2)*2 =
     = 7 - (3.50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000) * 2 =
     = 7 - 7 =
     = 0
```

> and gives result 1 when I execute the command: echo "7%2" | bc

From the `bc` manual:

> *scale* defines how some operations use digits after the decimal point.   The  default  value of *scale* is 0.

In that case:

```
a=7    b=2
a/b = 7 / 2 = 3 # scale is 0, rounds down
a%b = a-(a/b)*b =
    = 7 - (7/2)*2 =
    = 7 - 3 * 2 =
    = 7 - 6 =
    = 1
```

Because the `7/2` is computed with different scale, the resulting expression differs.